# How to download with curl error userinfo auth0

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests

I get a message instead of an m3u file

{"user_info":{"auth":"0"}}
how to download it note it is normally downloaded via telnet or on firefox
url
https://pastebin.com/ysAGBfWU

```
import os, os.path

if not os.path.exists(M3UPATH):
    #os.system('wget --no-check-certificate -q -O- --trust-server-names %s > %s' % (url, M3UPATH))
    os.system('curl --limit-rate 100k -n -s -k -L %s -o %s > /dev/null 2>&1' % (url, M3UPATH))
```

Comment: I'd guess the website is asking you to authenticate